# How to make all parts of fraction, except numerator, disappear while keeping original position of numerator (or how to align at numerator with `&`)?

Tags: amsmath, fractions, phantom

I have split the issue I have into 2 problems and decided to post them at once to avoid semi-duplicate since they are closely related. First is to render all parts of a fraction (including the line) invisible except the numerator (or denominator), retaining position of that numerator. Second is to align a variable of an equation to a numerator of a fraction of another equation using `aligned` environment (which I failed to do with `&` character).

#### original code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $%
        \begin{aligned}
&\frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}=x\\
&a=x\cdot\frac{b}{c}
        \end{aligned}
    $
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Problem 1

#### enclosing entire fraction except numerator (`a`) into `\phantom` makes numerator (`a`) itself disappear along with fraction and distorts alignment

```
&\frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}=x\\
&\phantom{\frac{}a\phantom{}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}}=x\cdot\frac{b}{c}
```

[image]

#### enclosing denominator into `\phantom` keeps unwanted fraction-line:

```
&\frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}=x\\
&\frac{a}{\phantom{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}}=x\cdot\frac{b}{c}
```

[image]

## Problem 2

#### aligning at numerator with `&` does not compile:

```
\frac{&a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}=x\\
&a=x\cdot\frac{b}{c}
```

The last piece of code was expected to align second-equation "a" not only horizontally with the first-equation numerator "a" (as shown in the image above) but also properly position it vertically with respect to the "equals" sign.

Comment: you can avoid the fractionbar by using `\genfrac` from `amsmath` but I'm struggling to guess what you want `\frac{&a}` to do (even `{&a}` would hide the `&` from the alignment  even if there was no fraction you can not align at arbitrary points in a subterm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't tell anybody, it's a secret trick.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\latehfil}{\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\hfil}

\begin{document}

$\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} &= x \\
a\latehfil &= x\cdot\frac{b}{c}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want to keep the “a” at the same height, but I can see no reason to,

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\latehfil}{\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\hfil}
\newcommand{\fraconlynumerator}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle\frac{#1}{#2}$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht0-\height}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} &= x \\
\fraconlynumerator{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}\latehfil &=x\cdot\frac{b}{c}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's `\latehfil`? The cells in odd numbered columns of `aligned` end up into a box containing

```
\hfil$\displaystyle{<cell>}$
```

and we want to add another `\hfil`. If we just issue `a\hfil`, the `\hfil` would end up in the braced subformula and have no effect. However, `a\aftergroup\hfil` would save `\hfil` for after the `}`. With `\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\hfil`, the steps are similar to

```
\hfil$\displaystyle{a\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\hfil}$
\hfil$\displaystyle{a}\aftergroup\hfil$
\hfil$\displaystyle{a}$\hfil
```

because the token following `\aftergroup` reappears after the group ends. A single `\aftergroup` might suffice, but symmetry is nicer.

The second trick is: measure the height of the full fraction. Then typeset just the numerator, raising it by the height of the full fraction minus its actual height.

Comment: @bp2017 Added some explanations

Comment: you just have to hope that no passing `amsmath` maintainer sees this and adds an extra group, just to stop people poking in internals...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the double jumping just in case somebody did that.

Comment: I find Werner's `genfrac` solution for rendering parts of fraction invisible much easier to comprehend but since you also provided solution for numerator alignment, your answer is accepted. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\genfrac` from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) which provides `gen`eric `frac`tion primitives:

```
\genfrac{<ldelim>}{<rdelim>}{<rule thickness>}{<math style>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>}
```

This works fine if you wish to hide the rule (setting `<rule thickness>` to `0pt`) and `\phantom` the denominator (equation (1) below):

[image]

However, hiding the numerator in the same way pushes the denominator up by the default rule thickness (equation (2) above). Instead, it's almost easier to use a combination of `\phantom`s (for content you want to hide) and colour (for hiding the rule) (equation (3) above):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
%  \frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}           &= x \\
%  \frac{a}{\phantom{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}} &= x \\
%  \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{a}{\phantom{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}} &= x \\
  \frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} =
    \frac{a}{\phantom{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}} =
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{a}{\phantom{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}} &= x \\
  \frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} =
    \frac{\phantom{a}}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} =
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\phantom{a}}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} &= x \\
  \frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} =
    \frac{\phantom{a}}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} =
    {\color{white}\frac{\phantom{a}}{\color{black}\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}} &= x
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @bp2017: It's defined inside [TeX the Program's `web` code](http://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Build/source/texk/web2c/tex.web). However, the default is usually `.4pt`.

Comment: For the reference, it seems that setting line thickness to any(?) negative value retains original spacing.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $
    \begin{array}{c@{\;=\;}l}
    \displaystyle\frac{a}{\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}&x\\
    a &x\cdot\frac{b}{c}
    \end{array}
    $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bp2017 See egreg's answer.